# Is it safe to remove photo library caches?

Tags: photos.app

I've noticed there is a caches folder inside of a Photos.app library package.

For example: `/Volumes/PhotosDisk/MyPhotoLibrary.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.mediaanalysisd/caches/`

In that `caches` directory there is a `vision` subdirectory that contains the following files:

```
AlgoFaceClusterCache.data
ED271675-D043-418D-9E4C-6A33C481CD66.cmap
FB2B5939-6CB2-43EE-8EC1-72EF6BCDEF3F.cmap
PersonPromoter
PhotoAnalysisServicePreferences.plist
clustererState.plist
faceWorkerState.plist
mediaAnalysisVersionState.plist
vnpersonsmodel.bin
vnpetsmodel.bin
```

The situation is that my Photos library hasn't done any work to detect faces in a few months now. The Console log doesn't really report anything but it does complain about an error loading the "persons model":

`Sandbox: photoanalysisd(5463) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/PhotoDisk/MyPhotosLibrary.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.mediaanalysisd/caches/vision/vnpersonsmodel.bin`

For what it's worth, the files in the caches/vision directory are all correct permissions as far as I can tell.

So my question is:

1. What are these files in the caches directory?
2. Are they safe to delete?

What I'm trying to achieve is un-stick the face detection of the photos library. This is my latest guess at what might be at fault.

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, I made a copy of the library and deleted the cache directory for the mediaanalysd "vision" subdirectory. Still able to launch the photos library and use it, but going to the People page shows "0 photos scanned of 57000", so presuming it means it is going to rebuild... but will update after it has a few days to grind away at it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Answering my own question because I did the experiment and can speak to the results.. other answers still welcome!)*

In general, it *appears* safe. By that I mean I deleted the subdirectories found inside:

`/Volumes/PhotosDisk/MyPhotoLibrary.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.mediaanalysisd/caches/`

and

`/Volumes/PhotosDisk/MyPhotoLibrary.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.photoanalysisd/caches/`

Deleted, rebooted, opened Photos.app again to kick things off. Opening the app causes a short "Updating library..." progress bar screen but then will go to the photo library.

What I noticed was that for starters, the People tab of the app said "0 pictures scanned of 57000". Given the slow progress that the analysis programs demonstrate normally, it wasn't surprising that this took a few weeks before anything started to move. However, I was no longer getting the same errors in the Console that I reported in the question since that file was re-created.

In general, the library is now detecting faces again and progressing without errors. It did mistake a few pictures of someone else in my family as me (and auto-tagged them), which I had to catch and tell Photos "XXXXX is not in this picture". So there MIGHT be a little re-training to be done. However, any existing face/name assignments remained despite deleting these cache directories.

So my cautionary advice to anyone else who might encounter this problem is to first *MAKE A BACKUP* (naturally), but then go ahead and delete anything inside the `cache` subdirectories. Expect the analysis tools to pretty much start over from scratch, but it should unblock the app and faces will start getting detected again, albeit after a few weeks.